# Central extensions of automorphisms of Bruhat-Tits trees

Tags: ergodic-theory, group-actions, gr.group-theory

This is the first time I am using Mathoverflow and I am still learning how to use it.
That is why I want to begin with a curious question:

Does the group of automorphisms of a Bruhat-Tits tree have nontrivial central extensions?

Comment: @Hadi: it seems like a perfectly good qustion, but people might be more interested if you added some motivation.  (Also, why is it tagged "ergodic-theory"?)

Comment: Are you just asking about the full automorphism group of a $q+1$-regular tree (which is quite large), or are you asking for the automorphisms to preserve some algebraic structure?

Comment: @Pete: The automorphism group of a tree and $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ have similar properties. It is probably natural to guess that their central extensions look similar as well (though it may merely be a wild guess.) There are also a result by Kapoudjian what says that a combinatorial analog of $Diff(S^1)$ has nontrivial central extensions.
@Scott: I mean the automorphism group which acts rigidly on edges, hence it is locally compact.